# Laravel: Load view in to a view via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I come to Laravel 4.x from Codeigniter & don't understand Laravel errors messaging. I am trying to load view into a view this is my code

**Route**

```
Route::get('widget/addcustomer', 'WidgetController@addcustomer');
```

**Controller**

```
public function addcustomer()
{
    return View::make('widget.addcustomer')->render();
}
```

**Main view.blade.php**

```
<script>
function loadwidget(1, 'formname', 1)
{   
    var widget_url = '<?php echo URL::to('widget'); ?>';

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: widget_url+'/'+formname,
        dataType: "html",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            $('#'+divid).html(response);

            if(active==0)
            {               
                $('#'+divid+' :input').attr('disabled', true);              
            }       
        }
    });
    return true;
}
</script>
```

**External view.php**

```
<form id="customer_form">
    <table><tr><td>....</td></tr></table>
</form>
```

but in fire bug I am getting

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException","message":"","file":"E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tt_kickoff\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php","line":210}}
```

and if I hit `http://localhost/tt_kickoff/widget/addcustomer`
it is loading correct html

Comment: post your routes file

Comment: Route: Route::get('widget/addcustomer', 'WidgetController@addcustomer');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routes file will have a `GET` method for `addcustomer()` - but you are "POST" to the route, so you also need a `POST` method.

Edit:

So you change

```
Route::get('widget/addcustomer', 'WidgetController@addcustomer');
```

to

```
Route::post('widget/addcustomer', 'WidgetController@addcustomer');
```

**OR** change your ajax

```
type:'POST',
```

to

```
type:'GET',
```

Comment: What is "divid" - I dont see that defined anywhere? Anyway - this fixed your route problem - now you have an ajax problem....